# showing some view in all activities without duplication of code in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, code-duplication

I have a condition when a specific event will  occur in background, I have to show a Floating Action Button in bottom of activity to notify the user if App in fore ground. No matter in what activity the  user is, if that event trigger by a service, I have to show a FAB not a dialog, I mean user can interact with activity and FAB both at the same time. How could I achieve this if I do not wanna repeat the same code in all activities of my app.

Comment: Have you considered "including" layouts ?

Comment: this is what `Notification`s are used for

Comment: For this purpose, I would have used `Snackbar`

Comment: I am working with geofences and if the geofence breached and app is in open state, I wanna  show a FAB with some animation, In  this case Notifications are of no use..

Comment: People just down vote the  question if don't have any answer to question. I am asking for help in design show i prevent some code duplication in all activities.

Comment: @lee Thanks, Thats what I think of  very first time but I just have  to show a FAB that will remain in any activity till some user does not exit geo fence. Snakebar  covers a lot of part of activity. So I have to drop the plan of using it for now.

Comment: `FloatingActionButton` is just a custom `android.widget.ImageView` so simply add it to the root `ViewGroup` by calling `ViewGroup#addView`, what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a utill class and make a static method in that class so in which activity you want to access that method just Classname.methodname and send parameter.
or you can use that method in that Activity and extend from that activity

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple activity that matches your need and make all other activities derived (inherited) from that one.

Comment: But all activities has  its own layouts,  I just need to show a FAB or any view in any currently opened activity, So i am not using any content_view for BaseActivity.

Comment: Yes, you have to create layouts for each activity, but you don't have to write redundant java code.